# How to color pandas plot in groups

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

If i have a pandas dataframe:

```
x = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,5), columns = ['0','1.1','1.2', '2.1', '2.2'])
```

and would like to plot it like this:

```
x.plot()
```

[image]

How do i color them by groups, like 0 in one color, 1.1 and 1.2 in one color, 2.1 and 2.2 in one color. I would like the legend still to say all five types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add a list of colors with the length of number of plots:
Instead of `x.plot()` you write:

```
x.plot(color=['r', 'g', 'g', 'b', 'b']) # red green green blue blue
```

Comment: this is not a good solution, dont hard code the length of numbers in the code that doesnt work

Comment: @MadhaviJ He asked for a possible way and I presented one, never said it is the most elegant way. The code in this example works!